# Get original height and width of a cached image's source in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

Is there any other way I can access the OriginalHeight and OriginalWidth within the ImageInformation of a CachedImage, other than checking for successful loading as follows?

```
CachedImage img = new CachedImage() 
{ 
    CacheType = FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.Memory 
};
img.Source = GetNextImage();
img.Success += (sender, e) =>
{
    h = e.ImageInformation.OriginalHeight;
    w = e.ImageInformation.OriginalWidth;

    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
    {
        if (h > w)
        {
            img.HeightRequest = 400;
        }
    }
    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
    {
        if (h > w)
        {
            img.HeightRequest = 800;
        }
     }            
 };
```

Comment: Is the image an embedded resource, like a PNG that is in the Resources folder? Or is it a URL that is hosted on the backend?

Comment: JPEGs with a build action of Android resource and Bundle resource for ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `FFImageLoading` library, your approach is correct w/ `Success`, but if you have images under Resource folder, maybe can use the approach/idea below:

**PLC/Standard:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourProject.Utils
{
    public interface IImageResource
    {
        Size GetSize(string fileName);
    }
}
```

**Android:**

```
using Android.Graphics;
using YourProject.Droid.Utils;
using YourProject.Utils;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImageResource))]
namespace YourProject.Droid.Utils
{
    public class ImageResource : Java.Lang.Object, IImageResource
    {
        public Size GetSize(string fileName)
        {
            var options = new BitmapFactory.Options
            {
                InJustDecodeBounds = true
            };

            fileName = fileName.Replace('-', '_').Replace(".png", "").Replace(".jpg", "");
            var resId = Forms.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", Forms.Context.PackageName);
            BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Forms.Context.Resources, resId, options);

            return new Size((double)options.OutWidth, (double)options.OutHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS:**

```
using YourProject.iOS.Utils;
using YourProject.Utils;
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImageResource))]
namespace YourProject.iOS.Utils
{
    public class ImageResource : IImageResource
    {
        public Size GetSize(string fileName)
        {
            UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(fileName);
            return new Size((double)image.Size.Width, (double)image.Size.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage w/ Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService:**

```
var imageSize = DependencyService.Get<IImageResource>().GetSize("ic_launcher.png");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(imageSize);
```

Another option via XAML:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="CachedImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ffimageloading:CachedImage}">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
           <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
           <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
             <Setter.Value>
               <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="800" Phone="400" />
             </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
         </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>

<ContentView.Content>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage
        x:Name="cachedImg"
        Style="{StaticResource CachedImageStyle}">
      </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    <!-- ... -->
</ContentView.Content>
```

And then, you can create a converter in order to set the tablet/phone size, maybe works.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: @Jadar in ios image returns null how to resolve it